# getting the filesize of a file

Tags: google-drive-api

In my program i need to retrieve the filesize of a file from the server and compare it with the local file size. I will be doing this from a .net desktop application. I will only the have filename(including path) with me.  How is it possible with google drive api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no knowledge of Google Drive SDK but the file function 'get' (Gets a file's metadata by ID- https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) outputs a body of information documented here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource which as a property '"fileSize": long'

Do you know how to implement APIs? Than this information should be sufficient.

EDIT:
If you only have the name you should iterate to all files and compare the file names. Then you do not have to use the 'get' function anymore, since you obtain all information of the files while iterating. You iterate with the 'list' function: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: yes, but GET takes an ID, I have a filename with me. how can i convert  filename to an ID?

Comment: See the edit above. Its about the 'list' function: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list